# JPA exception while mapping to entities

Tags: java, jpa

Hi I'm writing one of my very first JPA projects and I'm kinda newbie in this field, so please try to simplify stuff as much as you can :)
Here's one of the entities

```
package model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@Entity

public class Speaker implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private Date dob;
    private String skills;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="event",cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    private Set <Session> speakerSessions;

    /**
     * @return the name
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    /**
     * @param name the name to set
     */
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    /**
     * @return the dob
     */
    public Date getDob() {
        return dob;
    }
    /**
     * @param dob the dob to set
     */
    public void setDob(Date dob) {
        this.dob = dob;
    }
    /**
     * @return the skills
     */
    /**
     * @return the skills
     */
    public String getSkills() {
        return skills;
    }
    /**
     * @param skills the skills to set
     */
    public void setSkills(String skills) {
        this.skills = skills;
    }
    /**
     * @return the id
     */
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    /**
     * @param id the id to set
     */

}
```

and here's the exception that gets thrown

```
   Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28019] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Deployment of PersistenceUnit [test] failed. Close all factories for this PersistenceUnit.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.IntegrityException
Descriptor Exceptions: 
---------------------------------------------------------

Exception [EclipseLink-93] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: The table [EVENT] is not present in this descriptor.
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(model.Speaker --> [DatabaseTable(SPEAKER)])

Exception [EclipseLink-41] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: A non-read-only mapping must be defined for the sequence number field.
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(model.Speaker --> [DatabaseTable(SPEAKER)])

Runtime Exceptions: 
---------------------------------------------------------

    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.createDeployFailedPersistenceException(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:816)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:756)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getAbstractSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:204)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:304)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:302)
    at Test.Tester.main(Tester.java:19)
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-28019] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Deployment of PersistenceUnit [test] failed. Close all factories for this PersistenceUnit.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.IntegrityException
Descriptor Exceptions: 
---------------------------------------------------------

Exception [EclipseLink-93] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: The table [EVENT] is not present in this descriptor.
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(model.Speaker --> [DatabaseTable(SPEAKER)])

Exception [EclipseLink-41] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: A non-read-only mapping must be defined for the sequence number field.
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(model.Speaker --> [DatabaseTable(SPEAKER)])

Runtime Exceptions: 
---------------------------------------------------------

    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException.deployFailed(EntityManagerSetupException.java:238)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.IntegrityException
Descriptor Exceptions: 
---------------------------------------------------------

Exception [EclipseLink-93] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: The table [EVENT] is not present in this descriptor.
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(model.Speaker --> [DatabaseTable(SPEAKER)])

Exception [EclipseLink-41] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: A non-read-only mapping must be defined for the sequence number field.
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(model.Speaker --> [DatabaseTable(SPEAKER)])

Runtime Exceptions: 
---------------------------------------------------------

    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.initializeDescriptors(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:689)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.initializeDescriptors(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:625)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.initializeDescriptors(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:565)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.postConnectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:792)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.loginAndDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:736)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryProvider.login(EntityManagerFactoryProvider.java:239)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:681)
    ... 5 more
```

I nearly have zero experience in this topic so please provide as much detailed info as you can :)

here's the session entity guys

```
package model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Date;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@Entity
@Table (name="session")
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery (name="findAllSessionForEvent",query="select e from Session e where e.event.id= :id"),
@NamedQuery (name="findSessionsBySpeakerName",query="select e from Session e where e.speaker.name=':name'"),
@NamedQuery (name="findSpeakerOfSessionBySessionId",query="select e.speaker.name from Session e where e.id=:id")})
@XmlRootElement

public class Session implements Serializable {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private int id;
    private Date date;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn (name="eventID")
    //@Column(name="eventID")
    private Event event;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn (name="speakerID")
    //@Column(name="speakerID")
    private Speaker speaker;
    /**
     * @return the date
     */
    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }
    /**
     * @param date the date to set
     */
    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public Speaker getSpeaker() {
        return speaker;
    }
    public void setSpeaker(Speaker speaker) {
        this.speaker = speaker;
    }
    public Event getEvent() {
        return event;
    }
    public void setEvent(Event event) {
        this.event = event;
    }


}
```

Comment: Please include the code for the `Session` class in your question.  The presence of `The table [EVENT] is not present in this descriptor.` in the exception suggests it is a problem with that entity relationship.

Comment: @NeilStockton what type should it be ?! I inserted it to have a mapping for the foreign key

Comment: If you have 1-N Speaker -> Session then the type on the Session side should be Speaker.

Comment: I already have a Session.speaker of type Speaker field ! didn't quite get what you was going for there

Comment: If you have Session.speaker then why is Speaker.speakerSessions having mappedBy=event ??? It should be "speaker". Any basic JPA relation handling tutorial would show this

Comment: that was the problem :) .. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have `Session.speaker` then why is `Speaker.speakerSessions` having **mappedBy=event** ??? It should be "*speaker*". MappedBy basically says what is the field at the other side of the relation

Answer (score 1):

You have to have correct schema structure in your underlying database and you have to have correct mappings in your JPA entities.

For the correct schema you can start by generating the schema by the JPA vendor. You can achieve that by adding one property to your persistence.xml file:

- If you are using EclipseLink:

  `<property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables" />`
- If your are using Hibernate:

  `<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />`

With them you should get rid of the `A non-read-only mapping must be defined for the sequence number field.` error. This error tells you that JPA provider doesn't have the table to generate Ids from.

Your second error `The table [EVENT] is not present in this descriptor.` could mean an issue with `@OneToMany` mapping to `Session`. Is Session an entity and does it have correct `@ManyToOne` mapping back to `Speaker`?

Comment: Why use vendor-specific properties when you can use "javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" ?

Comment: Good point! If you are using JPA 2.1 (JEE 7) then yes, of course.

Comment: I'm already generating the schema by eclipselink, and added the session entity, seems to me that the mapping is ok!

Answer (score 0):

Error says - "A non-read-only mapping must be defined for the sequence number field."

Try adding the setter for your 'Id' field in Speaker.java

Ie. Add this code to Speaker.java -

```
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

Comment: Not correct. `@Id` annotation present on the field means JPA is defaulting to Field Access for all properties in the entity. JPA does not use setters nor getters in this case but manipulates entity fields directly.

Answer (score 0):

> Exception Description: The table [EVENT] is not present in this descriptor.

Add

```
@Table(name="Schamaname.Tablename")
```

or

```
@Table(name = "Tablename", schema = "Schamaname")
```

Add getter and setter for id. If you get NullPointerException initialize id with constructor

```
public Speaker (int id) {
    this.id = id
}
```

or change int to Integer, because int cannot be "null" in java, but as far it is primary key it should never be null in database.

You might also need @NamedQueries.

Comment: did all of that :) same exception

Comment: Don't comment @Column(name="...") and show us your persistance.xml. I suggest you to create a very simple example, without any join etc...